# React Native - How to build expo react native app so that it does not require Expo android app to open

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, build.gradle, expo

i have Developed a React Native app using expo. I build it using expo amd downloaded and installed apk file but still using Expo app to open app in the android phone. But i want that it can be installed and run without expo app so that i can share it with my friends. I think I have to use Android studio for that , right?? But I'm a newbie and I don't know how to use Android Studio. I have ejected App from expo and i have Android folder with me. Please guide what to do next to make my app sharable and publishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the distribution section of the Expo documentation: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/introduction/

Comment: So according to that document, I don't need android studio. And also i don't have to upload it on Play store so i can skip that keystore section right???